# find -printf on Mac (-printf unknown option)

Tags: macos, find

I have a little bit of code that I use to get an MD5 sum of the most recently modified file time

```
find ./media -type f -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p \n" | sort | more | tail -1 | md5 -r | awk '{print $1}'
```

I use it for generating unique keys for my CDN files, the logic behind this is if a file changes the key changes so the files are un-cached and reloaded.

Anyway, when I try to run that on my Mac I get the error '-printf unknown option'
I looked through the man page but couldn't find anything similar, how do I get this too work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`printf` is specific to GNU find and not available on OS X's `find` by default.

Install [findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) on your Mac, e.g. using [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) using the following command:

```
brew install findutils
```

You can alternatively use Macports or Fink, they likely also have this package available.

To actually use gnu find you will need to use `gfind` since `find` will still link to OSX's `find` located in `/usr/bin/find`.

Homebrew comes with a [tap](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes) for cases where system commands are duplicated by the commands installed via homebrew.
Simply do `brew tap homebrew/dupes`, and then for above example `brew install findutils`.
Now you should be able to use homebrews find command without having to explicitly call it via `gfind`.

Comment: ...and once you've installed findutils, the command that is installed is named gfind (gnu find)

Comment: brew tap homebrew/dupes homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `-ls` flag instead to get the same information (and then some), which might work just as well for your purposes.